# Does the zero locus of a real analytic function have a smooth point?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations, analyticity

Let $F \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a real analytic function (i.e., each of its component functions is real analytic).  Does the set
$$Z = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^m : F(x) = 0\}$$
have a smooth point?  If not, what is an explicit example of such a set with no smooth points?  Assume $Z$ is not empty.

By $x \in Z$ is a smooth point, I mean there is an open set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ containing $x$ such that $Z \cap U$ is a smooth manifold.

[Comments: I know this is true if $F$ is a polynomial map (and so $Z$ is an affine variety).]

Comment: I know that for the complex analytic set the set of smooth points are dense open subset, I'm not sure if it applicable for the real analytic case?

Comment: Slightly trivial remark but of course for $Z$ to have any chance of having a smooth point it has to be nonempty, so presumably you want to assume that $Z$ is nonempty.

Comment: Edited the question to specify non emptiness.

Comment: @yili Do you have a reference for that result?

Comment: Sure, You can found the proof on Demailly's Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry  Proposition 4.24. But it's not so easy to prove

Comment: Another classic text to explore is H. Whitney's *Complex Analytic Varieties*. There are all sorts of important foundational things in there. (I no longer own the book, so don't ask me where to look.)

Comment: After some digging, I believe $Z$ does always have a smooth point, and this follows from the Whitney stratification of real analytic varieties: see Theorem 1.2.10 in this survery [https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-03186972/document] or see Lojasiewicz's structure theorem (Chapter 6 in https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-8176-8134-0).  **However, I could be wrong, I am not knowledgeable in this field.**